# Why Lord Chaitanya leaves his incarnation in Puri dham?

Tags: krishna, vishnu, chaitanya

I'm going to visit puri dham in coming days.Now I have a query in my mind, is there any specific reason Why Lord Chaitanya leaves his life in Puri dham?

If anybody has answer please tell me in short form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as Lord Chaitanya, Sri Krsna accepts the mood of Srimati Radharani (and that is why Lord Chaitanya's color is golden, like the color of Radharani). Puri Dhama is a place where the *vipralambha* (separation) pastimes of Lord Chaitanya occur. You see, in Puri, the Lord becomes almost completely immersed in the mood and *mahabhava* of Radharani. Just like when Lord Krsna leaves Vrndavana and resides in Dwaraka, Radharani burns in separation from Him; Lord Chaitanya although seeing Lord Jagannatha (who is Krsna but in Dwaraka) burns in separation from Him in the mood of Radha. And just like Radha is consoled by Her Sakhis, Lord Chaitanya is consoled by Swarupa Damodara (who is Visakha) and Ramananda Raya (who is Lalita). Chaitanya Charitamrta describes that the Lord was so intense:

> svakīyasya prāṇārbuda-sadṛśa-goṣṭhasya virahāt
>   pralāpān unmādāt satatam ati kurvan vikala-dhīḥ
>   dadhad bhittau śaśvad vadana-vidhu-gharṣeṇa rudhiraṁ
>   kṣatotthaṁ gaurāṅgo hṛdaya udayan māṁ madayati
>
> “Because of separation from His many friends in Vṛndāvana, who were like His own life, Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu spoke like a madman. His intelligence was transformed. Day and night He rubbed His moonlike face against the walls, and blood flowed from the injuries. May that Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu rise in my heart and make me mad with love.”

When this mood of separation reached it absolute climax, the Lord left His body (some say He merged into the deity of Lord Jagganatha, others say He merged into the Ganga, some say into Tota Gopinath). So the reason is, Puri Dhama represents the separation pastimes of Lord Chaitanya and its subsequent climax and that is why He left at that place.

Comment: What does "mahabhava" refers? @Nitai dasa

Comment: @GopalBiswas Mahabhava refers to the highest mood of ecstatic love (Prema) between the Lord and His devotees. There are many levels of Love for God. It goes Prema, Pranaya, Mana, Sneha, Raga, Anuraga, Bhava then finally Mahabhava.  Mahabhava is only possessed by certain devotees, and Radharani's Mahabhava (called Adhirudha Mahabhava) is the highest form of Love towards Krsna (no-one else can attain it, or rival it). It is a very high topic...I am afraid I cannot describe it fully in few words. /\

Comment: @GopalBiswas It is my pleasure to share something about Lord Chaitanya. Please enjoy your visit to Puri Dhama and get Lord Jagganatha's blessings. Be sure also to visit the temple of Sri Tota-Gopinath. Jaya Nitai!